# Mysql In clause select all records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, in-clause

I have a store procedure like this:

```
select * from A where A.column1 IN (parameter) AND A.column2 IN (parameter2)
```

So, I need to know if there is any way to select all records in the column1 when 'parameter' is empty (the same for column2 with parameter2)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A 
where (parameter is null or A.column1 IN (parameter))
  and (parameter2 is null or A.column2 IN (parameter2))
```